# Ruby MVC and text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, textfield

I have this code which I don't really understand:

app\controllers\look_controller.rb

```
class LookController < ApplicationController
 def at
  @data_hash = params[:cruncher]
  @cruncher = Cruncher.new(@data_hash[:crunch])
  @data = @cruncher.crunch
 end
 def input
 end
end
```

app\models\cruncher.rb

```
class Cruncher
 attr_reader :crunch
 attr_writer :crunch
 def initialize(data)
  @crunch = data
 end
end
```

app\views\look\input.rhtml:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Using Text Fields</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Working With Text Fields</h1>
  This Ruby on Rails application lets you read data from text fields.
 <br>
 <%= start_form_tag ({:action => “at”}, {:method => “post”}) %>
 Please enter your name.
 <br>
 <%= text_field (“cruncher”, “crunch”, {“size” => 30}) %>
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type=”submit”/>
 <%= end_form_tag %>
 </body>
</html>
```

I do not understand what is the relationship between `<%= text_field (“cruncher”, “crunch”, {“size” => 30}) %>` and the model. What do text_fields attributes cruncher and crunch have to do with the model?

As I understand the params is a special hash that stores the data from the user, and by using `@data_hash = params[:hash]` inside the controller we store that data.

But what about this `@cruncher = Cruncher.new(@data_hash[:crunch])`, why do we now use `@data_hash[:crunch]`?

Why not just `@data_hash?`

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--`cruncher` is the model, `crunch` is the property. You use `@data_hash[:crunch]` because that's what `Cruncher` expects in its constructor.

Comment: Where did you dig up this oddity? Guessing from the use of `.rhtml` it looks like Rails 1 code.

Comment: I found it in some rails tutorial book

Answer (score 1):

if you look at he html produced by the input view, you'll see something like this for the text field:

```html
<input type="text" name="cruncher_crunch" value="cruncher[crunch]" size="30" />
```

this means that the params hash, created when the form is submitted, and sent to the `LookController#at` method will be formatted like this:

```rb
{cruncher: {crunch: 'somevalue'}}
```

which is exactly the format that the `Cruncher.new(@data_hash[:cruncher])` expects.

Answer (score 1):

Its not that strange that you don't understand it.

This code is probably ludicrously old (`.rhtml` and `start_form_tag` put it at Rails 1 or 2) and really bad, it does not even run as there are two syntax errors as well as the quotes that look like an artifact from pasting the code into MS Word

```
# don't put a space before parens when calling methods in Ruby!
text_field (“cruncher”, “crunch”, {“size” => 30})
```

It would also give NoMethodError on `@data = @cruncher.crunch`.

In Rails 5 the same example can be written as:

```
class Cruncher
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :crunch

  def crunch
    # have no idea what this was supposed to do
  end
end
```

```
class LookController < ApplicationController
  def at
    @cruncher = Cruncher.new(cruncher_params)
    @data = @cruncher.crunch
  end

  private

  def cruncher_params
    params.fetch(:cruncher).permit(:crunch)
  end
end
```

```
# I really have no idea what the actual routes are supposed to be
<%= form_for(@cruncher, url: '/look/at') do %>
  <%= f.text_field(:crunch size: 30) %>
<% end %>
```

Its still just a strange and non RESTful example though. Sometimes garbage code is best left buried.

> I do not understand what is the relationship between <%= text_field
>   (“cruncher”, “crunch”, {“size” => 30}) %> and the model. What do
>   text_fields attributes cruncher and crunch have to do with the model?

Nothing. There is no data binding. Its just a plain-jane text input.

> But what about this @cruncher = Cruncher.new(@data_hash[:crunch]), why
>   do we now use @data_hash[:crunch]?

Because the author didn't know what they where doing. And probably had not figured out that you can pass hashes to your methods.